# 100% width but without unique class [CSS]

Tags: html, css, forms, pardot

I am trying to code a form to include a Yes/No question at the end but ignore the 2 column structure the rest of the webform is built with. 
Here is the form: http://www2.idioplatform.com/l/20742/2018-01-03/59bg11

I cannot change the HTML structure because it is handled by our marketing automation system but I can add CSS or Javascript to change things.

What I want is essentially this: http://prntscr.com/itvry9
So that the last  with .col-sm-6 to have 100% width in order to position it on the left side and use 100% of the space. But I cannot add a unique class to it (only to the div inside this div).

Is there any way to do this? Or would you do it in a different way?

Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: FYI, questions should include code that demonstrates the issue and that also allows answerers to try out fixes onto that code. Please see **[ask]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

logicdigger

```
div#linkedin + div.row > .col-sm-6.col-xs-12:last-child {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```